# Appending a tail-select option maintaining the functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

Created a select tag using jquery tail module: https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select 
I want to append a new option input taken from the user.

Using nodejs for this local server to automate file movement.

```
tail.select(".selectBox_custom",{placeholder:"Add custom"});
$("#idofselect")[0].options.add("New Option",true);
```

I expect to see the newly added option post this action. Whereas, the html source shows the new option but is not visible on tail select element on browser. Also, I don't believe that the functionality of multiple select is also added if somehow I could get the element to be displayed.

Also tried with following documentation, but could not get a clear demo:
https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select/wiki/public-methods#addkey-value-group-selected-disabled-description-rebuild

Comment: A simple fiddle: jsfiddle.net/3c9w2yke/20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in documention you had provided:

> This function will NOT rebuild the dropdown field, unless you pass
>   true as last argument!

So. it means that you have to provide `true` to your `add()` method call. Smth like this:

```
$("#idofselect")[0].options.add("New Option",true, false, false, false, '', true);
```

---==== EDIT ===---

I was able to add new option to tail select following documentation you had provided. I would suggest you to use for all select manipulations `instance` variable, it is going to save your debugging time and your code became more cleaner and readable. Here the sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/83sg97Lc/).

Comment: @VinayGupta why? Can you share any details in order to get help?

Comment: Should it work? I could not find any demo..If you have this in working state, could you please share the fiddle link? My workflows are complex and any more information will make it confusing.

All I can say is that, I have a multiple select tag using tail. I want to add one more option in the list. A simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3c9w2yke/20/

Comment: @VinayGupta I updated my answer with fully working fiddle.

Comment: Marked this as answer. The issue with my code was :
let instance = tail.select("select", { /* Your Options */ });

I tried re instantiating the element with class.

Answer (score 1):

Hellow,

It's not documented, but it's highly recommended to fill in the first both arguments on the `options.add()` method (so the key and value, even if it is the same). To update the dropdown field, you can use the `tail.select.query()` method on your own.

I wrote a small [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sambrishes/pen/ymoMMB) to demonstrate this.

Sincerely,
Sam, Developer of tail.select.

Comment: Thanks @SamBrishes. query() api is another thing I learnt from your answer. Just curious to know, what is the difference between:
let select = tail.select("select");    
and 
var tailSelect = $(".classOfSelect");   //Getting variable using jquery

Comment: `tail.select(".selector", { /* Options */ })` is just the vanilla JavaScript equivalent (and the recommended way) to jQuery's `$(".selector").tailselect( /* Options */ )` implementation. (So the tail.select script doesn't depend on jQuery, it just supports it).

If the first argument of the `tail.select()` constructor is a STRING, it will call [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) by its own. So you can pass any valid selector you want to (but you can also pass an Element, NodeList, HTMLCollection or Array of Elements).